# Syntax error in Macro expansion

Tags: c++, c, macros

How does the TEXT("x") macro expand to L"x" if unicode is defined and "x" if unicode is not defined because when I try to compile the following code it says "error #1049: Syntax error in macro parameters."

```
#define T("x") "x"

int main()
{
}
```

Comment: The above code wouldn't do anything even if it did compile; what is the intent here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup the `tchar.h` header in your installation. You'd get something like the following:

```
#define __T(x)      L ## x
```

In Unicode mode, the above macro pastes an `L` and a string argument together. In ASCII mode, there is no prefix to paste so it goes simply as:

```
#define __T(x)      x
```

Note that you invoke this macro indirectly, via another macro -- `_T()` (with a single underscore) and pass a string literal as argument.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define T("x") "x"
```

That defines a macro function `T`, and what would be a parameter named `x` if there weren't any quotes. You could try something like this instead:

```
#define T(x) #x
```